# Null checks in Scriban

Tags: sxa, scriban

I want to check for null values in Scriban.

```
{{ if (o_model.address.id) }}
<div  style="text-align: center;"><h5>Address {{ o_model.address.id}}</h5><br /></div>
{{ end }}
```

I am getting this error

```
error : Object `o_model.address` is null. Cannot access member: o_model.address.id
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried something like `if (o_model.address && o_model.address.id)`?

Comment: Not sure what part of `Object o_model.address is null` is unclear

Comment: @MarkCassidy thanks it works

Comment: @MarkCassidy Marek solutions works thanks

Comment: See https://github.com/scriban/scriban/issues/191

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```
{{ if (o_model.address)}}
    {{ if (o_model.address.id)}}
    {{ end }} 
{{ end }}
```

Thanks Marek